# Svelte input field text length check

Tags: svelte

Learning Svelte.js library and cant seem to be able to solve below issue.

For some reason value of `l` is evaluated incorrectly, which can be seen in console.

I'm thinking that maybe the `on:input` is incorretly used `<textarea>` or `check()` function is incorrectly built.

```
<script>
let t = ''
$: l=t.length
    
    function check() {
        if (l > 5) {
            console.log(l)
        }
        console.log(l)
    }
</script>

<h1>Am I a good Svelt dev?</h1>
<p>My code:</p>
<textarea on:input={check} bind:value={t} />
<p>{l} chars. {l>240?'NOPE':'I ❤️ Svelte'}.</p>
```

Seems I am not able to figure it out - hence I am unable to do proper text length validation check.

Code can be copied and run on the web:
https://svelte.dev/repl/b0fd6b152bb54383beab850f0feb5e0e?version=3.44.0

Comment: Whats the problem. Code seems to work fine and no console messages.

Comment: The code you posted here is not the code in the REPL. Both seem to do what they are supposed to. With the check function you are logging the length always once and twice if its length is greater than 5. What's your exact goal or where do you see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As voscausa said, the code in the REPL seems to work just fine, but doesn't include the `check()` function. If you use `on:keyup` instead of `on:input`, the value of l should be correct.

Comment: Why change to on:keyup - on:input works fine? With on:keyup more event than necessary (like pressing Shift) are triggered

Comment: This solved the problem - `on:keyup` instead of `on:input` evaulates `l` correctly.

To be more precise for others who posted - if you copy and execute my code - and watch numbers closely in console you will see that `l` evaluates incorrectly.

Comment: Sure, I was blind... but it's harder to understand a problem if the problem is 'incorrect output' instead of 'logging 0 when it should be 1' - precise description helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your problem is that the `length` that is logged seems incorrect

```
a -> 0
ab -> 1
abc -> 2
```

This is due to `on:input` being evaluated *before* the `bind:`

So what happens is:

- the length is 0 because the string is empty
- user presses `a`
- the `on:input` triggers
- the `check` function evaluates the length, but this is still empty and therefore 0
- the `bind:` triggers and the string is updated
- user presses `b`
- `on:input` triggers
- `check` now sees a length of 1 because the string is `a`
- `bind:` set the string the `ab`

If you want to check the length of the *current* string in your input event you will have to take it from the event parameters

```js
function check(ev) {
  const length = ev.target.value.length
  // other stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After realizing, that the problem lies in the fact that on:input is triggered before l is reactively updated, an alternative way to the already mentioned solutions

1. run on:keyup (triggers more often than necessary)
2. get the length directly in check(event) via event.target.value.length

would be to not listen to an event on the textfield, but simply 'listen' to changes of the length and then run the check function with this syntax

```js
$: l=t.length
    
$: l && check()  // check() is run when l changes and is true

// or

$: l, check()  // check() is run every time l changes
```

the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/dc74df5e8b9e43509d1e783f5e603538?version=3.44.0)

```html
<script>
    
let t = ''

$: l=t.length
    
// $: l, check()  // triggers every time l changes

$: l && check()  // triggers every time l changes and is true
    
function check() {
 if (l > 5) {
   console.log(l)
 }
   console.log(l)
}
    
</script>

<h1>Am I a good Svelt dev?</h1>
<p>My code:</p>
<textarea bind:value={t} />
<p>{l} chars. {l>240?'NOPE':'I ❤️ Svelte'}.</p>
```

I don't know if there's a name for this kind of 'listening'/'quick subscription'. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304022/svelte-execute-function-when-any-of-group-of-variables-changes), connection with ',' and '&&' might even be combined.